# Minimizing multivariable, constrained linear function with bounds in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I have to minimize the following function:

```
def foo(x):
        sigma1 = sum([sum([KS * x[U + e * K + k] for k in range(K)]) for e in range(E)])
        sigma2 = sum([W * c for c in x[U + Y: U + Y + X]])
        sigma3 = sum([T * z for r in x[U + Y + X:]])
        return sigma1 + sigma2 + sigma3
```

where KS, U, K, E, W, Y, X, T are constants and x is a vector of numbers in range [0;1].

Additionally, several constraints have to be matched:

```
cons = [
        {
           'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, k=k, e=e:  x[U + K * e + k + 1] - x[U + K * e + k]
        }
        for k in range(K - 1) for e in range(E)
    ]

cons += [
        {
            'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, r=r, c=c: x[U + Y + X + r - 1] - x[U + Y + c]
        }
        for r in range(R)
    for c in range(C)
    ]
cons += [
        {
            'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, e=e: sum([M * x[U + e * K + k] for k in range(K)]) - sum(V * x[E * d + e] for d in range(D)])
        }
        for e in range(E)
    ]
cons += [
        {
            'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, k=k, c=c, e=e: x[U + Y + c] - x[U + e * K + k]
        }
                for r in range(R)
            for c in range(C)
        for e in range(E)
    for k in range(K)
    ]
cons += [
        {
            'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x, d=d, i=i: sum(x[E * i + e] for e in some_dict[d["ENTRY"]].values()) - 1
        }
        for i, d in enumerate(dicts)
    ]
```

, where M,V,D,C are constants and dicts is a lists of dictionaries, carrying also dictionaries under "ENTRY" key.
Initial guess vector:

```
init_guess = [1] * (U + C + Y + Z)
```

Minimization:

```
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=foo, x0=init_guess, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, options={"maxiter": 5000}, bounds=[(0, 1) for _ in range(len(init_guess))])
```

However, the output looks as the following:

```
nfev: 159
fun: 17480.0
status: 6
njev: 1
   x: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
 message: 'Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem'
 jac: array([    0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
       0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
       0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
       0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
       0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
       0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
       0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
       0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,    15.,
      80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,
      80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,    80.,
      80.,    80.,    80.,  1500.,  1500.,  1500.,  1500.,  1500.,
    1500.,  1500.,  1500.,  1500.,  1500.,     0.])
 nit: 1
 success: False
```

Not only do I not understand why it fails, but also why the Jacobian matrix, although calculated correctly, has an additional '0' at the end (so it is 1 element longer than initial guess vector). I have tried sending the Jacobian explicitly, but the result was still the same. I cannot use other minimization methods, as only SLSQP can handle both 'eq' and 'ineq' constraints, as well as bounds. If scipy.optimize.minimize is not a good tool for this, could anyone suggest another Python library, which is able to solve this problem? I am not familiar with linear optimization, but I have to do this in Python.

Comment: Could you turn this into a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by providing example values for your parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use GLPK/Python: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Python. It's free, open-source, it can solve LP's and MIP's and you can find it in many linux repos.